# how can i fix aws ec2 "statuscheckfailed" problem?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, server

My ec2 Information

1. os : ubuntu
2. cpu : t2.micro (for freetier)

[0903 status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxWxm.png)

[0907 status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMIRk.png)

[0908 status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80iLX.png)

What i do , What i know

1. It happens almost same time.
2. I checked NetworkIn , NetworkOut, CPUUtilization.
3. I use docker ( only for oracle11gXE )
4. I use tomcat
5. I edit inbound rules all port source (0.0.0.0/0)

[0903 cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7JWM.png)

[0907 cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CQ3V.png)

[0908 cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyslq.png)

How can i fix it?

Comment: You may need to monitor memory as well, not provided out of the box, but you can configure it by installing CloudWatch agent, here's a link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html. In addition you could send system logs to CloudWatch as well, allowing you do a post-mortem.

Comment: @petern thank you!! your advice is so helpful! From now on, I will use 'cloudwatch' xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS provides a **detailed guide** on what to do when an instance fails a status check:

- [Troubleshooting instances with failed status checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html)

Depending on a possible cause you have a number of options to deal with them, as listed in the guide, ranging from rebooting the instance, restarting or migrating to new instance type.

Comment: The problem was Mysql restarting -_-;; I just 'service mysql stop' -> and problem solved... I don't know exactly how it fixed. but  your advice was very helpful. thank you so much !